# Authorisation via Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

We have implemented authentication via OAuth 2 in `Developer Portal` of `API Management` and `AAD` within an internal network.

How should I go about implementing authorisation? I cannot find any doc from MS doc site :(.

https://tointegrationandbeyond.com/blogs/index.php/2020/06/13/authorization-with-azure-api-management/
https://www.cloudfronts.com/securing-an-api-using-oauth-2-0-in-azure-api-management-part-3-oauth-2-0-server-setup/

Comment: Here is the MS docs that you are looking for [Protect API backend in API Management using OAuth 2.0 and Azure AD - Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) and [Authorize developer accounts using OAuth 2.0 in API Management - Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2).

Comment: that is authentication, I am looking for authorisation.

Comment: Did you happen to check this blog? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538#:~:text=Azure%20AD%20OAUTH2.0%20authorization%20in%20APIM%20OAUTH%202.0,a%20valid%20OAuth%20token%20that%20APIM%20can%20validate.

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. I will have a proper look.

Answer (score 1):

The API Management is a proxy to the backend APIs, it’s a good practice to implement security mechanism to provide an extra layer of security to avoid unauthorized access to APIs.

To use OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure AD:

We need to have

•   An API Management instance

•   An API being published that uses the API Management instance

•   An Azure AD tenant

And then we need to

1. Register an application (backend-app) in Azure AD to represent the API.
2. Register another application (client-app) in Azure AD to represent a client application that needs to call the API.
3. In Azure AD, grant permissions to allow the client-app to call the backend-app.
4. Configure the Developer Console to call the API using OAuth 2.0 user authorization.
5. Add the validate-jwt policy to validate the OAuth token for every incoming request.

Please check this reference docs for more clarification [Protect API's using OAuth 2.0 in APIM](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20OAUTH2.0%20authorization%20in%20APIM%20OAUTH%202.0,a%20valid%20OAuth%20token%20that%20APIM%20can%20validate)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad